# Restoring annotations from a PDF corrupted by Mac's Preview application from raw PDF text

Tags: macos, pdf, corruption

## Summary

The 'Preview' Application for viewing and editing PDFs, native to MacOS has an annoyin bug which seems to exist since 'High Sierra' and is still not resolved in the current OS version 'Catalina'.
It manifests in the following way:

- Multiple PDFs are opened and annotated with several text-highlights or comments
- The PDFs are saved but left open
- The Preview application quits unexpectedly but offers to reopen all files
- When doing so the files contain a seemingly random subset of all saved annotations
- Even when opening the corrupted PDF with Acrobat Reader DC most of the annotations are gone.

## Things I tried

Yesterday this bug occurred to me after some significant work on multiple PDF files, causing me to look into the issue.
As the files I had open were stored inside a synced folder, I had access to several versions of the files I was working on.
I noticed two things:

1. for some reason, even versions that were synced at a time when I had made most annotations but **before the crash occurred** would only display a subset of the annotations.
2. the file sizes were increasing with time, making me assume that the missing annotations were still stored in the file but were somehow corrupted and thus not displayed.

This made me think that Preview saved new annotations in some corrupted form, but is still somehow able to handle viewing them - at least for a while until it crashes.

Searching the web for solutions I came across [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224750/preview-seems-to-have-corrupted-pdf-and-lost-all-text-and-arrow-annotations) thread where `qpdf` was suggested to 'repair' PDFs (`qpdf  --qdf  original.pdf  unpacked.pdf`) but this didn't fix the problem in my case.

Instead I decided to look at the source of the raw PDF in text format, to see if I could discover something.
As I expected, searching a corrupted PDF for my user name brought up a large list of matches, apparently one for each annotations I had made.
On the other hand, doing the same for a file 'repaired' with `qpdf` only brought up matches for the annotations that would actually display in the PDF.
I tried to figure out some pattern in the source code of annotations that showed up vs. those that don't, but was not successful so far.

## Question

My hope now is that someone can spot what is going wrong in the source code of annotations that do not show up in order to fix this mess.
The question I am interested in is:

**Is there some way to edit a PDFs source code (preferably automatically) to recover the annotations that have been corrupted by Mac's Preview app?**

## Exemplary references

Evidently we first need to figure out know what is going wrong.
As I am not allowed to upload the PDFs themselves, I provide some excerpts from the source which I believe to be relevant, feel free to ask for more snippets!
The exerpts contain references to the obj identifiers of two notes which appear and two that don't.

#### notes that appear

- "1741 0" - (4 to 5 references)

  - at line 3865

    ```
    106 0 obj
    << /Annots [ 116 0 R 117 0 R 118 0 R 119 0 R 120 0 R 121 0 R 122 0 R 123 0 R
    1740 0 R 1741 0 R 1742 0 R ] /Type /Page /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.245 793.92 ]
    /Resources << /Font << /F1 776 0 R /F2 791 0 R /F11 463 0 R /F4 766 0 R /F5
    771 0 R /F7 786 0 R /F8 453 0 R >> /Properties << /MC55 108 0 R /MC56 114 0 R
    /MC51 110 0 R /MC52 112 0 R >> /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI
    ] /ExtGState << /GS3 752 0 R /GS7 751 0 R /GS5 462 0 R >> >> /Parent 739 0 R
    /B [ 811 0 R 810 0 R ] /Rotate 0 /Contents 107 0 R /StructParents 7 /CropBox
    [ 0 0 595.245 793.92 ] >>
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 8953

    ```
    1739 0 obj
    [ 116 0 R 117 0 R 118 0 R 119 0 R 120 0 R 121 0 R 122 0 R 123 0 R 1742 0 R
    1741 0 R 1740 0 R 1757 0 R 1759 0 R 1760 0 R 1758 0 R 1791 0 R 1792 0 R 1793 0 R
    1815 0 R 1823 0 R 1824 0 R 1957 0 R 1958 0 R ]
    endobj
    1740 0 obj
    << /F 4 /Type /Annot /Rect [ 297.7432 133.1971 369.7432 169.1971 ] /DA (/Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g)
    /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /M (D:20200728145314Z00'00') /C [ 0.984314 0.360784 0.537255
    ] /Subtype /Popup >>
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 8963 (directly after previous reference)

    ```
    1741 0 obj
    << /C [ 0.984314 0.360784 0.537255 ] /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /DA (/Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g)
    /F 4 /Subtype /Highlight /Type /Annot /Rect [ 42.816 110.6414 293.7432 129.1971
    ] /M (D:20200728145314Z00'00') /AP << /N 1750 0 R >> /Contents (So turning off multi-start to get a better comparison!)
    /QuadPoints [ 271.8799 129.1971 293.7432 129.1971 271.8799 121.0995 293.7432
    121.0995 42.816 118.739 103.5295 118.739 42.816 110.6414 103.5295 110.6414
    ] /T (Marco Langiu) >>
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 10721 (might not be an actual reference)

    ```
    0001031741 00000 n
    ```
  - at line 11414:

    ```
    106 0 obj
    << /Annots [ 116 0 R 117 0 R 118 0 R 119 0 R 120 0 R 121 0 R 122 0 R 123 0 R
    1740 0 R 1741 0 R 1742 0 R ] /Type /Page /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.245 793.92 ]
    /Resources << /Font << /F1 776 0 R /F2 791 0 R /F11 463 0 R /F4 766 0 R /F5
    771 0 R /F7 786 0 R /F8 453 0 R >> /Properties << /MC55 108 0 R /MC56 114 0 R
    /MC51 110 0 R /MC52 112 0 R >> /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI
    ] /ExtGState << /GS3 752 0 R /GS7 751 0 R /GS5 462 0 R >> >> /Parent 739 0 R
    /B [ 811 0 R 810 0 R ] /Rotate 0 /Contents 107 0 R /StructParents 7 /CropBox
    [ 0 0 595.245 793.92 ] >>
    endobj
    ```
- "1833 0" - (5 references)

  - at line 3875

    ```
    124 0 obj
    << /Annots [ 134 0 R 135 0 R 136 0 R 137 0 R 138 0 R 139 0 R 140 0 R 141 0 R
    142 0 R 143 0 R 1833 0 R 1834 0 R ] /Type /Page /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.245 793.92
    ] /Resources << /Font << /F7 786 0 R /F1 776 0 R /F2 791 0 R /F4 766 0 R /F11
    463 0 R /F5 771 0 R >> /Properties << /MC68 130 0 R /MC69 132 0 R /MC63 128 0 R
    /MC64 126 0 R >> /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] /ExtGState
    << /GS3 752 0 R /GS7 751 0 R /GS5 462 0 R >> >> /Parent 739 0 R /B [ 809 0 R
    808 0 R ] /Rotate 0 /Contents 125 0 R /StructParents 8 /CropBox [ 0 0 595.245
    793.92 ] >>
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 9475

    ```
    1832 0 obj
    [ 134 0 R 135 0 R 136 0 R 137 0 R 138 0 R 139 0 R 140 0 R 141 0 R 142 0 R
    143 0 R 1833 0 R 1834 0 R 1842 0 R 1850 0 R 1851 0 R 1867 0 R 1866 0 R 1868 0 R
    ]
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 9483 (directly after previous reference)

    ```
    1833 0 obj
    << /C [ 0.984314 0.360784 0.537255 ] /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /DA (/Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g)
    /F 4 /Subtype /Highlight /Type /Annot /Rect [ 33.006 264.2444 284.3759 324.65
    ] /M (D:20200728150458Z00'00') /AP << /N 1835 0 R >> /Contents (Which result is in agreement with 2017?)
    /QuadPoints [ 202.8095 324.65 284.2632 324.65 202.8095 316.5524 284.2632 316.5524
    33.006 314.183 284.297 314.183 33.006 306.0854 284.297 306.0854 33.006 303.725
    284.36 303.725 33.006 295.6274 284.36 295.6274 33.006 293.2671 284.3759 293.2671
    33.006 285.1695 284.3759 285.1695 33.006 282.8 283.9609 282.8 33.006 274.7024
    283.9609 274.7024 33.006 272.342 190.5361 272.342 33.006 264.2444 190.5361
    264.2444 ] /T (Marco Langiu) >>
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 11423

    ```
    endobj
    124 0 obj
    << /Annots [ 134 0 R 135 0 R 136 0 R 137 0 R 138 0 R 139 0 R 140 0 R 141 0 R
    142 0 R 143 0 R 1833 0 R 1834 0 R 1967 0 R ] /Type /Page /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.245
    793.92 ] /Resources << /Font << /F7 786 0 R /F1 776 0 R /F2 791 0 R /F4 766 0 R
    /F11 463 0 R /F5 771 0 R >> /Properties << /MC68 130 0 R /MC69 132 0 R /MC63
    128 0 R /MC64 126 0 R >> /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] /ExtGState
    << /GS3 752 0 R /GS7 751 0 R /GS5 462 0 R >> >> /Parent 739 0 R /B [ 809 0 R
    808 0 R ] /Rotate 0 /Contents 125 0 R /StructParents 8 /CropBox [ 0 0 595.245
    793.92 ] >>
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 11508

    ```
    1966 0 obj
    [ 134 0 R 135 0 R 136 0 R 137 0 R 138 0 R 139 0 R 140 0 R 141 0 R 142 0 R
    143 0 R 1833 0 R 1834 0 R 1967 0 R ]
    endobj
    ```

#### notes that do not appear

- "1454 0" - (2 references)

  - at line 6194

    ```
    1256 0 obj
    [ 57 0 R 58 0 R 59 0 R 60 0 R 61 0 R 62 0 R 63 0 R 64 0 R 65 0 R 66 0 R 67 0 R
    68 0 R 69 0 R 70 0 R 71 0 R 72 0 R 73 0 R 74 0 R 75 0 R 76 0 R 77 0 R 1257 0 R
    1258 0 R 1273 0 R 1281 0 R 1282 0 R 1297 0 R 1306 0 R 1307 0 R 1309 0 R 1305 0 R
    1308 0 R 1346 0 R 1347 0 R 1345 0 R 1369 0 R 1371 0 R 1370 0 R 1405 0 R 1404 0 R
    1421 0 R 1420 0 R 1437 0 R 1445 0 R 1454 0 R 1453 0 R 1464 0 R 1462 0 R 1463 0 R
    1479 0 R 1488 0 R 1489 0 R 1487 0 R 1511 0 R 1519 0 R 1900 0 R ]
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 7316

    ```
    1454 0 obj
    << /C [ 0.980392 0.803922 0.352941 ] /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /DA (/Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g)
    /F 4 /Subtype /Highlight /Type /Annot /Rect [ 371.6818 519.4665 500.5739 527.5641
    ] /M (D:20200728132511Z00'00') /AP << /N 1455 0 R >> /Contents (why three? What happens with the other ones?)
    /QuadPoints [ 371.6818 527.5641 500.5739 527.5641 371.6818 519.4665 500.5739
    519.4665 ] /T (Marco Langiu) >>
    endobj
    ```
- "1957 0" - (3 to 4 references)

  - at line 8953

    ```
    1739 0 obj
    [ 116 0 R 117 0 R 118 0 R 119 0 R 120 0 R 121 0 R 122 0 R 123 0 R 1742 0 R
    1741 0 R 1740 0 R 1757 0 R 1759 0 R 1760 0 R 1758 0 R 1791 0 R 1792 0 R 1793 0 R
    1815 0 R 1823 0 R 1824 0 R 1957 0 R 1958 0 R ]
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 10179

    ```
    1957 0 obj
    << /C [ 0.984314 0.360784 0.537255 ] /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /DA (/Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g)
    /F 4 /Subtype /Highlight /Type /Annot /Rect [ 499.8235 529.6356 527.8006 536.1137
    ] /M (D:20200728151906Z00'00') /AP << /N 1959 0 R >> /Contents (Wall time would have been interesting as well!)
    /QuadPoints [ 499.8235 536.1137 527.8006 536.1137 499.8235 529.6356 527.8006
    529.6356 ] /T (Marco Langiu) /Popup 1958 0 R >>
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 10186 (directly after previous reference)

    ```
    1958 0 obj
    << /F 4 /Type /Annot /Rect [ 531.8006 540.1137 603.8006 576.1137 ] /DA (/Helvetica 12 Tf 0 g)
    /Parent 1957 0 R /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /M (D:20200728151910Z00'00') /C [ 0.984314
    0.360784 0.537255 ] /Subtype /Popup >>
    endobj
    ```
  - at line 10698 (might not be an actual reference)

    ```
    0001021957 00000 n
    ```

Comment: You may be interested [in this post on Apple‘s Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251532057?answerId=251532057021#251532057021) where someone managed to recover the lost references. I wrote a little tool to automate the technique which I [published to GitHub](https://github.com/julihoh/pdf_annotation_fix). It can be used to revover lost annotations automatically. It does this by searching for a top-level array of references inside the pdf file, which is a true superset of the annotations that are attached to a page. If it finds such a superset, it blindly replaces the annotations for

Comment: The comment from @julihoh is perfect (and should probably be an answer if it was less reliant on links). The issue in the Apple forums explains the issue and how it is solved, and the tool linked on Github successfully retrieved all my 357 missing annotation. Thanks so much!